# What is a friendlier way to write "at the * preference" and "at the * convenience"?

Tags: expressions, idioms, sentence, writing-style, writing

What is a friendlier (and correct) way to write the following?

```
at the family's preference (at the family preference)

at the citizens’ convenience (at the citizens convenience)
```

Comment: At their **pleasure**? Lexico says under [**pleasure**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/pleasure): "Phrases **at someone's pleasure**. As and when someone wishes."

Comment: More context is needed, but "as you prefer" or "as you choose" has a less strident sound to it.

Comment: You haven’t demonstrated that the original wording is unfriendly.

Comment: @Lawrence I'm not sure whether the wording is friendly or not,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common error (faux-pas) made in incoming phone messages is the receiver saying "I will return your call at my convenience." That's a non-welcoming use of the *convenience* phrase. It is polite to ask one to do something at "Their convenience" not your own. Otherwise you are saying "I'll do it when I'm good and ready." Here saying *"At your preference"* or *"At your convenience"* is polite enough.

The context I would assume here is to describe what a hypothetical family or citizen may choose to do. Consider whether it is a family or an individual, a friendly word for citizen, being described. Then whether they may want to do it or not is their *preference*. Whether they might be able to do it or not is their *convenience*. Any combination of these would certainly be understood.

Answer (score 0):

Much of English language (as with most languages) situation, familiarity, intent, along with other factors, dictate how and what is proper in phrasing or word selection. Without a more explicit outline it is difficult to gauge what may be deemed most appropriate or correct. For example in closing out a formal letter or message in which you anticipate a response, I generally find it most proper to close with something to the effect of "At your earliest convenience" I would be inclined to say that "at convenience" would be more suited. However as previously stated, many factors play a part. Both however in this context convey that the responding party is at will to decide, and are being approached in a polite manner.